# Why is Unicode allowed in tag names?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, unicode, tags

On this webpage, one of 1000s that I am scanning, I found a tag name with Unicode 0x97 in it.

It uses

```
<!?~V[if lt IE 7]>
which contains 0xc2 0x96
```

According to a unicode converter c2 96 is

```
U+0096 START OF GUARDED AREA
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
```

I'd say the encoding is not unicode, it's [windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251).

The line you're asking about reads:

```
<!—rating forum -->
```

That "weird" character is an [em dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash). My experience with these is that they're usually the result of typing `--` (double hyphen) into Microsoft Office Word which then auto-corrects it to an em dash.

It's not valid HTML, but it works in the browser because browsers generally try to fix up broken HTML as best they can. In this case, you have an element that starts with `<!`, enough to guess that, while not the valid `<!--`, it's still probably the beginning of an embedded comment.